# Java Regular Expression to check for fixed length and more

Tags: java, regex

I am not even sure if regular expressions are the best way to do this. Here is the requirement on a string:

1. To check length is 13 characters
2. First and Last 2 characters are always characters only.
3. Characters from 3 - 11 are numeric.

Please suggest whether regular expression is the best way to do it and what the regular expression would like to check such a thing?

Regards
Akhil

Comment: Yes, you can use regex for this: `^[a-z]{2}\d{9}[a-z]{2}$` with `i` modifier

Comment: Just for clarification's sake, when you say that first and last 2 characters are always characters only, you mean an alphabetical character, A to Z, right? Are they always going to be either uppercase or lowercase, and if so which one?

Comment: If you have to craft an expression to do this it means it will be difficult to understand later.  If you write a simple loop with a few tests it'll be clear and easily updated by anyone.  If you ever have to post to ask about a regex, A) You've already wasted more time than you would have just doing it in code and B) You'll waste more time next time you go to mess with it.  If you know regex well enough to do it without asking then it should be okay (unless anyone else ever has to look at your code)

Comment: @Kaddath My comment was prefixed with "If you have to ask" and my point was that, in that case it will take longer and you probably will have to ask again to modify it--do you disagree?  If you already know it and every dev on your team knows it then I agree that it makes a great tool!  That's obviously not true of Akhil's team, even if it's a one person team..

Comment: I never said don't be curious. What I am saying is that it's your responsibility to use the clearest possible code that suits your team. Code isn't for a computer to read (if it was, basic would be fine), it's for the next person in your team to read (or you). Regex has it's place and you should know it (Along with all the other tools available to you)--it's the best (almost only) way to apply a user's query to data in your code--but consider carefully if it's clearer for everyone than a more explicit alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Use e.g.

```
"^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{9}[a-z]{2}$"
```

The square brackets say what is allowed, 'a-z' means small alphabetics between a and z. The curly says how many must be there. ^ means no characters before this, and $ means no characters after.

Usage:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MatcherExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "aa123456789bb";

        String patternString = "^[a-z]{2}[0-9]{9}[a-z]{2}$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        boolean matches = matcher.matches();
        System.out.println("Matches: " + matches);
    }
}
```

Comment: A short breakdown of the expression might help the OP since he obviously doesn't know much about regex.

Comment: wow..this was so quick and can I also say, it was the first time ever I used stackoverflow. Many thanks everyone specially tkruse

Comment: This doesn't cover the Capital letter cases nor UTF-8 characters of other languages!

Comment: @Akhil use the accept button to accept an answer. Also listen to the others about the limitations of this regex. If you have capital letters or different letters you will need small modifications.

Comment: @tkruse just add `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`